# Can I use native libraries in Appcelerator Titanium?

Tags: android, ios, titanium, appcelerator

In Appcelerator Titanium we do everything in Javascript. I wonder whether it's possible to use some self-defined native Java or Obj-C libraries and call the library functions from Javascript. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Don't know about Appcelerator Titanium, but Phone Gap allow you to write custom plugins to interact with native API's and your own code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use native library(Objective C) in Appcelerator Titanium. But for that you have to create Titanium Module.

Refer below guide for iOS Module Development in Titanium

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/iOS+Module+Development+Guide

Hope this helps you